# Fatal error: Class 'Smarty_Internal_Template' not found

Tags: php, modx, smarty

Не могу зайти в админку `modx`. Пишет следующую ошибку:

> Fatal error: Class 'Smarty_Internal_Template' not found in
>   /home/users/v/vasilykosenko/domains/metallotorg.am/core/model/smarty/Smarty.class.php
>   on line 444

Comment: Попробуй переустановить модикс. Что-то явно не так с системными файлами.

Answer (score 0):

Пробоема была в нехватки файлов в папке smarty